# Apache Rewrite Rule Regex Problem

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have an Apache .htaccess file that contains this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(javascript/.*)$ /$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/(styles/.*)$ /$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php
```

Unfortunately, the last line's coughing up a 500 error on the server that we've moved the code to. It works fine on my machine, Ubuntu 9.10 running Apache 2.2.12, but not on the server running Apache 2.2.14.

Is there any way to rewrite it so that the server doesn't return that error?

Answer (score 0):

The following variations may work

```
RewriteRule ^/.*$ /index.php
RewriteRule ^.+$ /index.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php
```

I know that this one,

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Works well for me on some of my mediawiki sites.

Comment: "RewriteRule ^/.*$ /index.php" and "RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php" didn't cause errors, but they weren't doing anything in terms of redirecting the url.